Are joins to heaps a performance concern if we can always force a hash join?
I clearly have a misconception, but no amount of consulting documentation has solved it. Consider the following argument:

We generally worry about joining to heaps, because sorting them is often more expensive than having a clustered index.
Hash joins require no sorts.
From the above, we conclude that you shouldn't worry about joining to heaps if you can always get (or force) a hash join.

The popular disdain for heaps suggests that the above is wrong, but where is it wrong?


The popular disdain for heaps suggests that the above is wrong, but where is it wrong?

This is wrong:

From the above, we conclude that you shouldn't worry about joining to heaps if you can always get (or force) a hash join.

Just because you don't need to sort the Heap doesn't mean you wouldn't benefit from it being filtered or some other operation where sorted lookups against it would be faster. You risk hashing the entire table if a filter operation can't be applied earlier in the plan and the entire Heap ends up being scanned.
With a clustered index, at least it's possible to be seeked on, or scanned more efficiently, reducing the amount of data being operated on earlier in the plan. Then what gets hashed is a much smaller dataset, making it a faster and more efficient operation.
At least that's one example.
Another more simplistic reason is you shouldn't always rely on HASH JOINs as your physical join operation because it isn't always the most efficient way to join two datasets together. By doing so, you throw away 2/3rds of the engine's other ways to potentially more efficiently join your data together.
